# Jquery redirect doesn't work on live server after submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm redirecting to pages based on the links clicked prior to login form submission. Form submitted via ajax, I noticed that only in live server, response passed from php script via ajax is not received.  `success: function(data) {//nothing works here}`.Thus the page is not redirected.In the php page, there's script to login the user. Surprisingly, after refreshing the page, user is logged in. AFter the user logged in, the redirection works perfectly.

I wonder why data is not passed from php via ajax and why redirection doesn't work?

My ajax..

```
$("#login").on("click",function()
          {
             // alert(this_link);
              $("#login_form").submit(function(){             
            var data = {
              "action": "test"
            };
            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "login2.php?id='"+this_link+"'", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                $(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data );
               // alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
              //alert(data);
              //alert(data["json"]);
              //console.log(data);

               if(data=="'del_create'-1")
                {
                     //window.location='create_post.php';
                     $(location).attr('href', 'https://sample.com/create_post.php');
                }
                else if(data=="'del_avail'-1")
                {                
                    //window.location='update_post.php';
                     $(location).attr('href', 'https://sample.com/update_post.php');
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location='<?php echo $root;?>login/login.php';
                }

              }
            });
```

data returned by php script

```
$id3=$id."-".$id2;
echo json_encode($id3);//returns 'del_avail'-1 or 'del_create'-1 if logged in and -0 if not logged in
```

Comment: write console.log(data) after success line and check whether data coming or not

Comment: `window.location` should be `window.location.href`

Comment: @Tushar you got it r8

Comment: @AbhishekPachal, I did, it's not coming on live server

Comment: @Tushar, I tried that and also window.location.replace too to no avail..I think the main problem now is ajax function is not showing data upon success..that means its not success. Because for other pages I used redirection and it worked

Comment: That means there is some problem with ur php script.It is not sending any json response back

Comment: @AbhishekPachal, yes thats right...but why it can send on localhost  but not on live server

Comment: another reason may be the url u are calling from ajax which is right for localhost not for live

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: another thing do not use php tag inside jquery.hold the value to an hidden dom and call by id.

Comment: @AbhishekPachal, no error on the console,, just that I dont see the php page called in network tab

Comment: Whats the value of $root here? make an echo of $root + exit() somewhere

Comment: @AramilRey, $root holds the rooth directory path

Comment: I mean if the script is accessing to that variable. Also you could get the root path with JS using window.location.origin +'etc...';

Answer (score 0):

Within the single quotes `echo` does not work. Perhaps the following will work.

```
window.location="<?php echo $root;?>login/login.php";
```

or

```
window.location.href="<?php echo $root;?>login/login.php";
```